# Don't know why my sound won't play in my app?

Tags: ios, core-audio

So I loaded a sound into my viewdidload method

```
//Loading Gunshot Sound
NSURL * Gunshotsound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]       pathForResource:@"Gunshot" ofType: @"mp3"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) Gunshotsound, &Gunshot);
```

in another method I tried to play the sound by using

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(Gunshot);
```

I can't figure out why it won't play.

Comment: Have you checked if `Gunshotsound` is `nil` or not?

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of research I found out that The AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function only works with .wav .caf or .aif files